# integrate Choco and Bloom filter

Tags: java, bloom-filter, choco

Now I am going to integrate Choco and bloom filter. The problem is I want to know which JAVA file in Choco is about search process because I want to store the decisions of each nodes into bloom filter after each searching step.

source code of choco: https://github.com/chocoteam/choco-solver

source code of bloom filter:
import java.util.BitSet;
public class BloomFilter {

```
private static final int DEFAULT_SIZE = 2 << 24;
private static final int[] seeds = {3,5,7, 11, 13, 31, 37, 61};
private static BitSet bits = new BitSet(DEFAULT_SIZE);  
private static SimpleHash[] func = new SimpleHash[seeds.length];  

public static void addValue(String value)  
{  
    for(SimpleHash f : func)
        bits.set(f.hash(value),true);  
}  

public static void add(String value)  
{  
    if(value != null) addValue(value);  
}  

public static boolean contains(String value)  
{  
    if(value == null) return false;  
    boolean ret = true;  
    for(SimpleHash f : func)
        ret = ret && bits.get(f.hash(value));  
    return ret;  
}  

public static void main(String[] args) {  
    String value = "xkeyideal@gmail.com";  
    for (int i = 0; i < seeds.length; i++) {  
        func[i] = new SimpleHash(DEFAULT_SIZE, seeds[i]);  
    }  
    add(value);  
    System.out.println(contains(value));  
}
```

}

class SimpleHash {

```
private int cap;  
private int seed;  

public  SimpleHash(int cap, int seed) {  
    this.cap = cap;  
    this.seed = seed;  
}  

public int hash(String value) 
    int result = 0;  
    int len = value.length();  
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {  
        result = seed * result + value.charAt(i);  
    }  
    return (cap - 1) & result;  
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The overall solving mechanism (which includes the search process in the "extend" case) is in the searchLoop() method of Solver: https://github.com/chocoteam/choco-solver/blob/master/src/main/java/org/chocosolver/solver/Solver.java

However, to retrieve what is done at each node you should simply use a monitor:

```
            model.getSolver().plugMonitor(new IMonitorOpenNode() {
                @Override
                public void afterOpenNode() {
                    System.out.println(s.getDecisionPath().getLastDecision());
                }
            });
```

This code prints every branching decision. 
You could also access other variable domains from there.

Comment: I followed your comment to add this in searchLoop() method and run a simple problem, the print out of some different nodes are the same. Could you please tell me your e-mail, we can communicate by e-mail. Thank you

Comment: You can contact me at jg.fages AT cosling.com

Comment: Here I have a new problem. If I open a new node and find it is the same as a node searched before then it will return true. And I want the search loop jump back when it returns true (it means when a searcher finds the new node is same as a node before, he will not go down anymore cause he knows there is no solution), how can I do that?

Comment: I do not understand how you could explore the same node twice. Can you explain what you are doing?

Comment: In simple terms, another java file will return a boolean value. If false Choco will continue search, if true Choco will back jump. How can I do that?

Comment: Could you please tell me which part is the back jump method.

Comment: I think you should give a look at model.getEnvironment().worldPopUntil(searchWorldIndex) method. For instance, we use it to perform a restart (pop until root node). Look at the code of Solver.restart() to see how it is used.

Comment: Thank you for comment. Now I need to do are 2 step: 1. If return a true, Choco will back track. 2. If there is no solution(the problem has a solution in fact, cause I return a true to let Choco back track), Choco will restart. How can I do? Thank you for your help

Comment: I think a clean way would be to implement your own Move object. Look at MoveBinaryDFS. More precisely, the repair() method performs one backtrack. You can change it in order to perform as many backtracks as you need.

Comment: I find reset() method is to back to the root node and solve the problem again. Could you please tell me where is the end of search process, I mean where can I add the reset() method?